# Cannot scan BLE devices around

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, sdk, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm working on Android Studio chipmunk using java language. Trying to discover Bluetooth Low Energy devices. Relevant Permissions are granted to the app but it still is not discovering devices around it. mLeDevices array size being zero returning null.

I am using Pixel 3 device to run my code with Android 12.

```
 private boolean scanning;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;

private LeDeviceListAdapter leDeviceListAdapter=new LeDeviceListAdapter();

    private ScanCallback leScanCallback =
            new ScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                    super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
                    LayoutInflater i = getLayoutInflater();
                    leDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(result.getDevice());
                    leDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            };

public void checkbluetooth(View view) {
        //Intent i =new Intent(this, DeviceScanActivity.class);
        //startActivity(i);
        getpermissions();
        BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = getSystemService(BluetoothManager.class);
        BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device doesn't support Bluetooth
        } else if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        }
        //findBle(bluetoothManager, bluetoothAdapter);
        BluetoothLeScanner bluetoothLeScanner = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        LeDeviceListAdapter leDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();
        leDeviceListAdapter.setLayoutInflater(getLayoutInflater());
        for (int i=0;i<2;i++){
            if (!scanning) {
                // Stops scanning after a predefined scan period.
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        scanning = false;
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                            return;
                        }
                        bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(leScanCallback);
                    }
                }, SCAN_PERIOD);


                scanning = true;
                bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(leScanCallback);
            } else {
                scanning = false;
                bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(leScanCallback);
            }}

    }
```

LeDeviceList Class:

```
public class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
    private LayoutInflater mInflator;

    public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
        super();
        mLeDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
    }

    public LayoutInflater getmInflator(){
        return mInflator;
    }

    public void setLayoutInflater(LayoutInflater li) {
        mInflator=li;
    }

    public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
            mLeDevices.add(device);
        }
    }

    public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
        return mLeDevices.get(position);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mLeDevices.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mLeDevices.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mLeDevices.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        // General ListView optimization code.
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
            //viewHolder = new RecyclerView.ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(view.getContext(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return view;
        }
        final String deviceName = device.getName();
        if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0)
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
        else
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);
        viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());
        return view;
    }
}
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView deviceAddress;
    public TextView deviceName;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
```

This is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.navigation" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission-group.NEARBY_DEVICES" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Navigation"
        tools:targetApi="32" >
        <activity
            android:name=".DeviceScanActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Get Permissions Method:

```
public void getpermissions(){
     //   if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31) {
            if ((ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) || (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ||
                    (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    || (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    || (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    || (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) ||
                    (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)||
                    (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION) !=
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)||
                    (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED) !=
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)||
                    (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission_group.NEARBY_DEVICES) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            )  {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
                        , Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
                        Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION,
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN, Manifest.permission_group.NEARBY_DEVICES,
                        Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED}, 1);
                //requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission_group.NEARBY_DEVICES}, 1);
                return;
            }
       // }
    }
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
                for (int i=0; i<permissions.length; i++){
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    int a =1;
                } else {
                    // Permission Denied
                    Toast.makeText( this,"Try Again" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }}
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Comment: BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission is a runtime permission. I don't see the request in the code.

Comment: All the permissions were granted by calling the getpermissions() method in checkbluetooth.

Comment: @AliAbdullah could you [edit] your question and add your getpermissions() method?